# Best way to reorganize dict in a specific string in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a dict.

```
some_dict = {'cars': 'Audi', 'price': '50k', 'year': '2016'}.
```

And I want a string:

```
cars=Audi, price=50k, year=2016
```

And I wonder, what is the best way of doing it?
There is always some option like this:

```
response = ''
   for key, value in some_dict.items():
        response += (str(key) + '=' + str(value) + ', ')
   response[-1]='.' # for replacing comma to a point
```

But it does not seem to be an excellent decision..
I am convinced there is a better way.

Comment: *‘, ‘.join(‘=‘.join(kv) for kv in dict.items())*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
some_dict = {'cars': 'Audi', 'price': '50k', 'year': '2016'}
', '.join('='.join(i) for i in some_dict.items())
```

Output:

```
'cars=Audi, price=50k, year=2016'
```

Comment: You could skip square brackets and will have not only two chars less, but instead of list comprehension you will have generator expression, which would be more efficient because will be no need to allocate memory for temporary list.

Answer (score 4):

A better single line and clean way would be:

```
print ", ".join(map(lambda x:"=".join(x), some_dict.items()))
```

First we join all the `key, value` pairs with `"="` sign to get a list of strings where keys and values are joined by `"="` and then we again `.join()` this list with `", "`.

To add more syntactic sugar as suggested by @juanpa.arrivillaga, you can simply use:

```
print ", ".join(map("=".join, some_dict.items()))
```

Comment: You can just use `'='.join` no need for lambda

Comment: You should remove the lambda solution

Comment: But I guess, the lambda solution gives some better insight as what is really happening @sstyvane, However the juanpa.arrivillaga solution is more Pythonic I admit.